# How to resolve Password verification failed Error

Tags: android

In my android Studio when I try to generate Signed Apk Bundle it give me Password verification failed Error I know the key store password and key password but still, it gives the same error.

Comment: did u fix it???

Comment: yes my key alias  was wrong  @Jeeva

Comment: passwords were interchanged

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have set correct key store path and selected correct key alias.